# How to make 2 colored text in a line in a marker infowindow?

Tags: android, google-maps, marker

I would like to make a marker info window, which has 3 lines, and every singe line contains 2 colors. 
I made the 3 lines with the help of

```
mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter()
```

but i am stucked with the colors.

Please Help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **SpannableString** to set multiple color in single string sentence in `TextView` or other text enabled component

```
String strMessage="I am android developer";
Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(strMessage);

//"I am android" red colored
spannable.setSpan(getTextAppearanceSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, android.R.color.RED)), 0, 12, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        textView.setText(spannable);


//"developer" blue colored
spannable.setSpan(getTextAppearanceSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, android.R.color.BLUE)), 14, strMessage.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        textView.setText(spannable);
```

**TextAppearanceSpan** method to customized text with color

```
/*
 *get customized text with color, style
 */
private TextAppearanceSpan getTextAppearanceSpan(int color) {
    ColorStateList blueColor1 = new ColorStateList(new int[][]{new int[]{}}, new int[]{color});
    return new TextAppearanceSpan(null, Typeface.NORMAL, -1, blueColor1, null);
}
```

Comment: there is method available in answer!!